# LWC component invokes apex controller in console app but need to restrict it on standard app

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a lwc component added on the case record page which is available in both console app and standard app. once case gets created on page refresh the component modal pops up. the @wire method is invoked two times on modal pop up for which the apex controller also hits two time. for standard app the apex controller is invoking in 2 different transaction at the same time.I am trying to fetch some data based on Case Id.Now if its 2 transaction same time then the data getting created twice for same CaseId.  how to prevent the second time data creation. I have added duplicate check but that is not working because its 2 different transaction same time.

```
@api recordId;
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
fetchData(response) {
    
    if(response && response.data) {
      this.queryData();
     }
 }
 queryData(){
 queryDataFromApex({ caseId: this.recordId })
    .then(result => {
    //code here
    }
.catch(error => {
        this.errorMsg = error;
        console.log('##--Error: ' + this.errorMsg);
    });
    
}
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this code from your parent component (LWC inserted in Lightning App Builder) or there is any another component calling this one?